# How to put two button in the same line using only html and css?

Tags: html, css

How do I properly align two buttons side by side with some space between them using css and html only?

Here is my [html](https://codeshare.io/5Xndkl) and [css](https://codeshare.io/5z94Kb). The two buttons are not aligned properly.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #0c0129;
  background-image: url(coding.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
}

.heading {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.title1 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50pt;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

.title2 {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.register {
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}

.register:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}

.login {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}

.login:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <span class="title1">Banerjee Solutions</span>
  <span class="title2">Your one stop shop for everything tech.</span>
  <ul>
    <li><button class="register">REGISTER NOW</button></li>
    <li><button class="login">LOG IN</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What do I need to modify to get the my desired result?

Comment: It is the `li`s that need to be aligned. `li { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }`

Comment: give the same margin for both button, actually one is having 50px and the other 20px

Comment: Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/varsha19/2a1pjqky/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my solution using `flex`

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

li {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution...but there is a border that appears when I click on any one the buttons, how do I get rid of that?

Comment: what colour is the border? I can't see one on mine

Comment: check https://www.dropbox.com/s/g72apjuxby8o69m/Untitled.png?dl=0 just zoom in 275% and u will c

Comment: @TamalBanerjee - what broswer are you using?

Comment: I can replicate the problem - i will try and fix it now - the issue wasn't happening on Firefox, but it is now on Chrome

Comment: i've fixed it - add this to your CSS 

button:focus {outline:0;}

Comment: yeah forget that...but when any of the buttons are clicked can you see a blue-ish border around the buttons?

Comment: @TamalBanerjee - if this helps please could you mark my answer as correct please - thank you

Comment: @TamalBanerjee see solution above

Comment: button:focus {outline:0;}

Comment: no worries - i'm glad that you persisted and got a thorough solution :)

Answer (score 1):

In your css classes you have more margin in your register class (using by the first button) than in your login class (using by your second button). They must have the same margin so they appears in line.

For instance put the login class the same as the register class, just like this:

```
.login {
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The li's of your list are block level elements - so to get the buttons to be on the same row - simply have the li's display: inline. Also the margins for each button were different - so making those the same allows them to be in line with each other. Each button is floated - one to the left and one to the right so each is positioned to the side of the container.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #0c0129;
  background-image: url(coding.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
}

.heading {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.title1 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50pt;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

.title2 {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.register {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}

.register:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}

.login {
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}

.login:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
 ul li {display: inline}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <span class="title1">Banerjee Solutions</span>
  <span class="title2">Your one stop shop for everything tech.</span>
  <ul>
    <li><button class="register">REGISTER NOW</button></li>
    <li><button class="login">LOG IN</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code

- Changed Element structure.
- removed float property , and added display: inline-block in login and register class
- added btn-container class

```css
.btn-container{
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #0c0129;
  background-image: url(coding.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
}

.heading {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.title1 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50pt;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

.title2 {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.register {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
}

.register:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}

.login {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
}

.login:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 1000ms, color 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <span class="title1">Banerjee Solutions</span>
  <span class="title2">Your one stop shop for everything tech.</span>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="register">REGISTER NOW</button>
    <button class="login">LOG IN</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a border that appears when I click on any one the buttons, how do I get rid of that?....if you look closely you can see that but its not easily visible..anyway it should not be there

Comment: You can set  outline: none; I have updated the code please check.

Comment: Can you send me screenshot?

Comment: check this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/g72apjuxby8o69m/Untitled.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated and working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly06krt3/25/

To summarize, you will want to float the `LI's` left, and give them both a width of 50% which will make them go side-by-side.

You then want add `auto` to the horizontal margins to align the buttons to the center of the `LI's`. So something like this: `margin: 50px auto`.